# wordpress facebook sdk publish_actions

Tags: wordpress, facebook

i want to make WordPress plugin or if already exists please tell me 
i want if user post 15 post on my WordPress site publish post to his Facebook wall with images and level and more than posts with another level

1. login to WordPress throw Facebook
2. save the access token to use it to publish offline
3. on save posts if equal certain number    publish the post to user
   time line

i do first step and this images the result

[image: login]

[image: request to post]

but no thing published to timeline  and the code is

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'xxxxxx',
  'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxx',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);

$helper = $fb->getCanvasHelper();
$permissions = ['email', 'publish_actions']; // optional
try {
    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
        $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
    } else {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    }
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
 }

if (isset($accessToken)) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    } else {
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
        // OAuth 2.0 client handler
        $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
        // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
        $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    }


    // validating the access token
    try {
        $request = $fb->get('/me');
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        if ($e->getCode() == 190) {
            unset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
            $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
            $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://apps.facebook.com/xxxxxxx/', $permissions);
            echo "<script>window.top.location.href='".$loginUrl."'</script>";
            exit;
        }
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    // posting on user timeline using publish_actins permission
    try {
        // message must come from the user-end
        $data = ['message' => 'testing...'];
        $request = $fb->post('/me/feed', $data);
        $response = $request->getGraphEdge()->asArray;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
    echo $response['id'];
    // Now you can redirect to another page and use the
    // access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
} else {
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    //$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://apps.facebook.com/xxxxxxxx/', $permissions);

    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl("http://www.xxxxxx.com/facebook/index.php",$permissions);
    echo "<script>window.top.location.href='".$loginUrl."'</script>";
}
```

help :)

Answer (score 0):

i used this tutorial to solve some steps

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XYawdJh_mNQ